# Moving mesh breaks uv

Tags: modeling, uv

When I'm moving mesh, uv is moving as well, breaking uv island (vertexes are merged, no seams are marked). It's something that happens from 2.8 version and happens quite often. Live unwrap is turned off.

Video: https://streamable.com/txphkz

Is it just a bug or I clicked something that cause it?

-I tried to move object to new scene - no problem.

-I tried to load scene without loading ui - problem exist.

Workaroud is to move object to new scene, but I'm seeking for solution of problem, not workaround.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't success with open your video, but it should be **Correct Face Attributes** option from your description:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: Set answer as correct, then